# How to fix 405 Method not allowed with okhttp

Tags: java, http, patch, okhttp

I'm getting

> 405 Method not allowed

when I try to patch the application using below code. How to fix it?

```
RequestBody body = new MultipartBuilder()
    .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
    .addFormDataPart("file", fileName, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/zip"), uploadZipFile))
    .addFormDataPart("artifactName", "gpswalker")
    .addFormDataPart("targetId", new Integer(SERV_ID).toString())
    .build();

Request request = new Request
    .Builder()
    .url(url)
    .patch(body)
    .addHeader("authorization", bearer_token)
    .addHeader("x-anypnt-org-id", ORG_ID)
    .addHeader("x-anypnt-env-id", ENV_ID)
    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no wrong in code, issue was with URL. and it is fixed.